# How to compare a value from the search bar to the one from the database in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to use the search box in my Laravel project but I keep getting the same error since morning

Here is my `Search controller`

```php
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class SearchController extends Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {

            return view('search.index');
        }
        public function Search(Request $request)
        {
            $serial_number= $request->input('search');
            $results =DB::table('animals')->where(function ($query) use ($serial_number) {
                $query->where('serial_number','LIKE',"%$serial_number%");
            })->latest()->get();
            return view('search',compact('results'));

        }
    }
```

`My routes`

```php
Route::get('/search','SearchController@index')->name('search');
Route::post('/search','SearchController@search')->name('search');
```

and finally my `view`

```html
    @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')
        <form action="{{ route('search') }}" method="POST">

            <div class="p-1 bg-light rounded rounded-pill shadow-sm mb-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Here the animal serial number..." aria-describedby="button-addon1" class="form-control border-0 bg-light">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button id="button-addon1" type="submit" class="btn btn-link text-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        @if($results)
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h3>Details for the animal</h3>

                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <p><strong>Id: </strong>{{ $results->id }}</p>
                                    <p><strong>Animal: </strong>{{ $results->type->category }}</p>
                                    <p><strong>Gender: </strong>{{ $results->gender }}</p>
                                    <p><strong>Place Of Birth: </strong>{{ $results->user->address->city }}</p>
                                    <p><strong>Farm: </strong>{{ $results->user->name }}</p>
                                    <p><strong>Date: </strong>{{ $results->created_at }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        @endif
    @endsection
```

For me, I think that the problem is in the `controller` on that line $result which makes the view give the error

> 419|Page Expired or "Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
>   Undefined variable: results (View: 
>    /Users/macair13/MeatracProject/resources/views/search/index.blade.php)"

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the CSRF token or exclude that URL from the CSRF token check.

```
<form ...>
    @csrf
    ...
</form>
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - CSRF](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/csrf)

Also you are not passing a `results` variable to your 'search' view from the Controller's `index` method. You will need to check if `$results` **`isset`** in your view or pass it to your view.

Comment: I have added it now I am getting this error "Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: /Users/macair13/MeatracProject/resources/views/search/index.blade.php)" which means the results variable is not working in the view but still can work when I use dd

Comment: `$results`, plural ... many, its not a single result, its potentially many results held in a collection

Comment: So all I am to change is the plural to singular

Comment: well naming things correctly helps but your query isn't asking for 1 record, it is asking for many ... there might only be 1 record that matches the query but it will always be in a collection because of the `get` call

Comment: So how am I to sort this

Answer (score -1):

```
  public function view (Request $request)
{
    $search=$request['search'] ?? "";
          if($search !=""){
              //where
              $data=File::where('id','like','%'.$request->search.'%')
              ->orwhere('name','like','%'.$request->search.'%')
              ->orwhere('file','like','%'.$request->search.'%')->get();


              
          }
          else{
            
            $data = File::all();
            
           
          }
          $p = compact('data','search');
          return view('upload_data')->with($p);

    // $data = File::all();
    // return view('upload_data',compact('data'));
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't see how this fixes OP's problem.